# Is Collectors.joining(",") thread-safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

Are `java.util.stream.Collectors::joining` implementations thread-safe? Can I do something like

```
public final class SomeClass {
  private static final Collector<CharSequence, ?, String> jc = Collectors.joining(",");

  public String someMethod(List<String> someList) {
       return someList.parallelStream().collect(jc);
  }
}
```

without fear of running into concurrency issues?

Comment: From what I remember it is not Collectors responsibility to handle thread safety. Collectors simply provides way explaining *where* to collect, but it is Stream which handles *when* to collect (which should also be thread-safe).

Comment: @Pshemo In this case multiple streams are using the same shared collector.

Comment: @Pshemo looking at the implementation it looks like it would work - I don't know if it is specific to this collector or if it is a derived result of their thread safety.

Comment: @assylias You are right. I was under false impression that `jk` `Collector` is using one `StringJoiner` for each joining so I was thinking that each stream should have its own separate `Collector`. But now I see that each call of `collect(jc)` will eventually create `new StringJoiner`, so using it in a way shown in question should be OK (unless someone will edit `someList` before stream will finish its collecting job but that is a problem of `someList` not stream).

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this collector as any other collector provided in `Collectors` class without fear of running into concurrency issues. The `Collector` need not to care about thread safety unless it has `CONCURRENT` characteristic. It just need to have its operations non-interfering, stateless and associative. The rest will be done by Stream pipeline itself. It will use the collector functions in the way which does not require the additional synchronization. In particular when `accumulator` or `combiner` function is called, it's guaranteed that no other thread is operating on the same accumulated value at the moment. This is specified in [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) documentation:

> Libraries that implement reduction based on `Collector`, such as `Stream.collect(Collector)`, must adhere to the following constraints:
>
> <...>
>
> - For non-concurrent collectors, any result returned from the result supplier, accumulator, or combiner functions must be serially thread-confined. This enables collection to occur in parallel without the `Collector` needing to implement any additional synchronization. The reduction implementation must manage that the input is properly partitioned, that partitions are processed in isolation, and combining happens only after accumulation is complete.

Note that the collector itself is stateless as well as functions it provides, thus it's also safe to have it in the static field. The state is preserved in the external accumulator which is returned by `supplier` and passed back to `accumulator`, `combiner` and `finisher`. So even if the same collector is reused by several stream operations, they don't interfere.

Comment: great answer, it is very generic